# How to modify an item in an IEnumerable collection and retain its order

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following situation. I have a list of items which have an "Id". I have to search for an item with a specific id, modify its values and maintain the order of the collection. What would be the best way to do that?

```
var collection = <some_linq_query>

collection.Where(i=>i.Id=someId).FirstOrDefault().Property = "bla";

// now collection should be the same but the item updated.
```

Comment: What is the LINQ query operating on?

Comment: ToDictionary does not preserve order, so you don't want it.  Here's the syntax:

Dictionary<int, ?> result = collection.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to Where does not modify the original LINQ query stored in `collection` in any way.  Instead it creates a new `IEnumerable<T>` where is a subset of the original query.  The subset will have the same relative ordering as the original set in `collection`

The only way this could cause a problem is if the value `collection` is a LINQ where which has a Where clause, or is otherwise filtered, base on the value of `Property`.  If that is the case and you want to preserve the order force collection into a non-lazy evaluated structure via .ToList.

```
collection = collection.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks this helped! Extra points if you can post me an example of using the property for the ToDictionary(..) method :D

Answer (score 1):

As long as the objects in the collection are mutable, your code should work fine.

By the way, `FirstOrDefault` takes an optional filter parameter, so you can write `collection.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == someId)`.

Comment: I don't think it is, if I add var item = collection.Where(i=>i.Id=someId).FirstOrDefault(); and hover over it with the debugger, the attribute is the old value.

Comment: Does your collection contain `struct`s?